# Python socket programming and LED interfacing

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to write socket programming in python. Whenever client sends message to server, LED should start blinking.
I'm running server program on Raspberry pi and client on PC.

Here is the code of server which is running on my Pi.

```
#!/usr/bin/python             # This is server.py file
import socket                 # Import socket module
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO       # Import GPIO library
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)      # Use board pin numbering
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)      # Setup GPIO Pin 11 to OUT
GPIO.output(11,False)         # Init Led off

def led_blink():
    while 1:
        print "got msg"         # Debug msg
        GPIO.output(11,True)    # Turn on Led
        time.sleep(1)           # Wait for one second
        GPIO.output(11,False)   # Turn off Led
        time.sleep(1)           # Wait for one second
    GPIO.cleanup()

s = socket.socket()           # Create a socket object
host = "192.168.0.106"        # Get local machine name
port = 12345                  # Port
s.bind((host, port))          # Bind to the port
s.listen(5)                   # Now wait for client connection.
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()       # Establish connection with client.
    print 'Got connection from', addr
    msg = c.recv(1024)
    msg1 = 10
    if msg == msg1:
        led_blink()
    print msg
    c.close()
```

Here is the code of client which is running on my PC.

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is client.py file
import socket               # Import socket module
s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = "192.168.0.106" # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # port

s.connect((host, port))
s.send('10')
s.close
```

I'm able to receive the message from client, But not able to blink the LED.
Sorry I'm new to coding. I've pretty good knowledge in hardware but not in software.
Please help me.

Comment: You are comparing a string with a number. Replace your server code with `msg1 = "10"`. If this doesn't work, do you see the "got msg" in your console ?

Comment: Within your `led_blink()` function is a `while 1` loop. Is that your purpose?

Comment: Yeah!! After replacing it with string I am able to blink the LED.   Thank You

Comment: removing `sockets` tag from this question, as you said in the answer your network stuff works fine.

Comment: @Arunkrishna Ok, putting official answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing a string `"10"` with a number `10`. Change your server code to :

```
msg1 = "10"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your PC or Raspberry and then edit accordingly:

```
#!/usr/bin/python             # This is server.py file
import socket                 # Import socket module

def led_blink(msg):
        print "got msg", msg         # Debug msg

s = socket.socket()           # Create a socket object
host = "127.0.0.1"        # Get local machine name
port = 12345                  # Port
s.bind((host, port))          # Bind to the port
s.listen(5)                   # Now wait for client connection.
print "Listening"
c, addr = s.accept()       # Establish connection with client.
while True:
    msg = c.recv(1024)
    print 'Got connection from', addr
    if msg == "Exit":
        break
    led_blink(msg)
c.close()
```

and:

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is client.py file
import socket, time               # Import socket module
s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = "127.0.0.1" # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # port
s.connect((host, port))
x=0
for x in range(10):
    s.send('Message_'+str(x))
    print x
    time.sleep(2)
s.send('Exit')
s.close
```

Note that I am using both the server and client on the same machine 127.0.0.1 and removed the GPIO bits as I don't have them available.

Comment: This answer resolves the infinite loop in the `led_blink()` function : at the exit the `GPIO.cleanup()` can be called!